# Access table based on selection criteria in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on application where I got to access data from 2 sheets, get the account number from first sheet and then look for those accounts in sheet 2.
I am using `OleDbDataAdapter` to select and count the number of occurrance but now the issue is to access those records out of all. 
One way I am thinking is to get the first occurrance row number, number of rows with specific account and use for loop to access each row.

Is there any other method you think of doing this.... Thanks,

```
oconn2.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter db = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet2$] where [Sheet2$].account_number= '" + account_number + "'", oconn2);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
db.Fill(dt);
int iRow = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Comment: I'd say that's fine - it's exactly what the OleDBDataAdapter is for - providing a SQL like query interface to a variety of data sources.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Daniel: its an intranet application. and the application cotains button events but not any textbox or anyother way to enter data

Comment: @user1661116 Bad practices are bad practices whether its an intranet application or not. Other developers could see this and think its the correct way to write queries.

Comment: Even though I agree with avoiding sql injection code, if account_number is an integer, what value would you set it to too cause a sql injection attack?

Comment: I finally got the number of rows, but can you guys please help me access each cell so that i can assign row values to variables?? Thanks,